# How to get base url in Unit Test?

Tags: magento2, base-url, unit-tests

This is my unit test in my custom module:

```
namespace Star\Trek\Test\Unit\Model;

class BeyondTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{

}
```

How can I get my Magento 2 base URL in there?

Comment: Sounds like you need an integration test, not a unit test.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to look into the core Magento unit test code how they use and get base URL.

I am not sure about this is what I shared is exactly you want, but I think it will help you.

Look into the Magento core test module.

> vendor/magento/module-cms/Test/Unit/Helper/Wysiwyg/ImagesTest.php

Find the function `public function testGetBaseUrl()` inside this function they get base URL `$this->imagesHelper->getBaseUrl();` using **imageHelper** they are use protected variable `protected $imagesHelper;` by class `\Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images`

---

**UPDATE:**

There is one anoter example of to get base URL using storeRepository look into the core module.

> vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/UrlRewrite/Model/StoreSwitcher/RewriteUrlTest.php

See the `public function testSwitchToNonExistingPage()` they are get store using object manager using `$storeRepository = $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface::class);` pass the storecode using `$toStore = $storeRepository->get($toStoreCode);` if you wan to get URL store specific.and finally get URL using `$toStore->getBaseUrl();`

I think it will help to solve out your issue.

Comment: I agree with this answer. So far anything I've seen uses objectManager.

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace Star\Trek\Test\Unit\Model;
class BeyondTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
        protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    /**
     * Prining URLs using StoreManagerInterface
     */
    public function getStoreManagerData()
    {            
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . '<br />';        
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_DIRECT_LINK) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_STATIC) . '<br />';
    }

}
```

Comment: This now becomes an integration test than a unit test I guess.